# Counting the number of rows returned from db_query() with the "SELECT" statement

Tags: 6, database

How do I find the total number of rows returned in `db_query()` for the `SELECT` statement, or the equivalent of `mysql_num_rows()`?

I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [`db_result()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database.pgsql.inc/function/db_result/6) documentation for Drupal 6:

```
function db_result($result) {
   if ($result && mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // The mysql_fetch_row function has an optional second parameter $row
    // but that can't be used for compatibility with Oracle, DB2, etc.
    $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    return $array[0];
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

I also saw that you could do this in Drupal 6:

```
$num_rows = db_result(
  db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {node} WHERE type = '%s'", $type->type)
);
```

It looks like you could simply do:

```
// Execute your query.
$result = db_query($your_query);
// Use mysql_num_rows() on the result set.
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: mysql_num_rows ? Yes I saw something like in internet too. This will do. This is great !

Comment: mysql_num_rows is deprecated in php 5.5.0 and up, so we'll need to use the available alternatives in the future.

Comment: and db_result is deprecated in Drupal 7

Comment: @Drilix - If look at the question it is tagged with drupal 6 not 7.

Answer (score 6):

```
$res = db_query("SELECT title FROM {node} WHERE  status = '%d'",  1);
```

`db_query()` returns an object, and you can check the total number of rows using `$res->num_rows`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you needs the number of rows before looping on the result set or not.

If you need it before, you generally make a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query with the same arguments as your first query and use [`db_result()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database.mysql.inc/function/db_result/6) to retrieve it.

If you need it after, just put a variable you'll increment during your loop:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node} WHERE status = 0");
$total_rows = 0;

while ($row = db_fetch_array($result)) {
  //Process your results here

  //Increment your counter
  $total_rows++;
}
```

Comment: Looping is all I want to avoid. I also want to avoid another query..

Comment: If so you should have specify this in your question in order to avoid being disappointed by answers and downvoting them ;)

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7 you can use

```
$result = db_query($query);
$result->rowCount();
```

Comment: For Drupal 7, THIS is the way to go.

Comment: No, because `rowCount()` is only for queries that affect rows like INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. See the discussion at https://www.drupal.org/node/1286238